# Display list of comments in reverse order on review website

Tags: php, arrays, comments, sorting

On a review website I would like to display the most recent comments first. The code I have is as follows:

```
<div class="comment_list">
    <ol>
      <?php wp_list_comments(array('callback' => 'commentslist')); ?>
    </ol>
  </div>
```

Any help most welcome, thanks for your time!

Comment: How to do this is described in the documentation of that function: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments. You should always consult the documentation before you ask a question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="comment_list">
    <ol>
      <?php wp_list_comments(array('callback' => 'commentslist', 'reverse_top_level' => false)); ?>
    </ol>
  </div>
```

You can see all the available options in [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments)